# How to get variable value from another python process?

Tags: python

I have pre trained boosting model as a pickle code. But when I try use this for prediction, deserialization from pickle code lasts over 3 seconds. It's critical for me.
I tried to use pickle, _pickle, joblib modules.
I cannot to predict in Flask app e.g. Every prediction open one python.exe process and then close it.

I think, I have to open one Python process, which will store deserialized models in memory.
So, how I can read deserialized model from another python process?

Comment: In general, you can't share variables between processes. You can try a memory-mapped file maybe.

Comment: Look at XML-RPC: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.client.html You can call functions and getting results in one python process from another.

Comment: Is it possible to save the model data in a different format? If the underlying model is in numpy arrays, numpy.save() might be faster, being a binary format.

Comment: @StanislavIvanov just as long as the "results" are XML-serializable, so you don't gain much from using XMLRPC over a rest/json api or any way of sharing data that relies on text serialization.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes. But python xmlrpc is very simple. For more complicated tasks we have https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/

Comment: thank you all. I tried numpy.load, but it is not faster. Also model is not json or xml serializable. will study mmap

Comment: @StanislavIvanov that link is deprecated, use https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/